# Displaying messagebox after MDB update

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

How would I:

1. Create a confirmation dialog (with only the ok option) after a successful MDB SQL entry - the form will close
2. Update **datagridview1** on form1 to reflect the new changes, this update could take place only once the user clicks on the ok button on the confirmation dialog or after the MDB SQL entry.

Currently the user is given no confirmation whether or not a SQL entry has been successful or not. Form2 is opened via Form1, and Form1 remains open while Form2 is open - hence the update would need to happen in the background. There would be no need to reopen Form1.

If you need any further information, please let me know.

This is the code that sets everything in motion:

```
private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (pgpText.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the following textbox: PGP");
    }
    else if (teamText.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the following textbox: Team");
    }
    else
    {

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            string pgp_new = pgpText.Text;
            string pgp_old = pgpOld.Text;
            string team = teamText.Text;
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='db.mdb'";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE PGP SET PGP=?,Team=? WHERE PGP=?";
            command.Parameters.Add("pgp_new", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pgp_new;
            command.Parameters.Add("team", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = team;
            command.Parameters.Add("pgp_old", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pgp_old;
            conn.Open();

            int affectedRows = (int)command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (affectedRows == 0)
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PGP (PGP,Team) VALUES (?, ?)";
                command.Parameters.RemoveAt(2);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I understand correctly...*

You want to:

1. open `Form2` from `Form1`
2. execute your SQL (in `Form2`)
3. close `Form2`
4. update `DataGridView` in `Form1`

This is a possible solution: First you have to set up your Form2 open method, treating it as a `Dialog`. You write something like this in `Form1`

```
private void openForm2()
{
    var f2 = new Form2(); //create new form2
    var formResult = f2.ShowDialog(); //open as Dialog and check result after close event
    if (formResult == DialogResult.OK) //check form2 dialog result
    {
        //form2 gave OK, I can update my DGV and display msg
        MessageBox.Show("DGV will be updated", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        //update my DGV
        UpdateDGV();
    }
    else
    {
        //form2 passed Cancel or something else, not good
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 Closed but nothing happened.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

Now that you have opened Form2 you must check if your query did something... if it was successful you can pass the OK result and close it. This is what happens in Form2

```
int affectedRows = (int)command.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (affectedRows == 0)
{
    //no records to UPDATE, will INSERT
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PGP (PGP,Team) VALUES (?, ?)";
    command.Parameters.RemoveAt(2);
    //rows affected by INSERT statement
    affectedRows = (int)command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

if (affectedRows > 0)
{
     //ok some rows were affected, close the form and pass OK result
     this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Finally, write your `UpdateDGV()` function in Form1 and update your data!!!

*There might be errors, but the general idea is this... good luck*

Comment: You should update your answer signaling the fact that if there is no record the affectedRows should be reinitialized by the insert statement

Comment: I'm trying to update datagridview1 which is on form 1